set the set $E=\{x\in X:\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)\} $ is measurable
let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable function then the set $E=\{x\in X:\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)\} $ is measurable
I know the standard strategy as using $\liminf-\limsup=0 $ but I wanted to know where m strategy fail ,
let's call $f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$  now $f$ is measurable because it's limit of sequence of measurable function
$E=\{x\in X:\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)\}=\cap_{m\in \mathbb{N}}\cap_{n\geq N}\{x\in X:|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{m}$}
and now this is like intersection of measurable set  because it's like $\{g<c\}$ where $g$ is measurable
my question is also why I necessary have to use cauchy definition? I think it is fine
UPDATE  the moral is :the measurability of limit function  depends on the limit function , if the limit function would have been  defined everywhere or a e     it would have been measurable because it would have been equal or equal a e to a measurable function    . this is not the case but we can see if the set where function has limit is measurable but we are not able to use that limit function is measurable

Have you proved why the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ is measurable?

@rafilou2003 yes limit of measurable function is measurable because liminf and limsup are measurable is it ok ?

I also noticed that you use ${x\in X , : , |f_n(x)−f(x)|<\frac 1m}$, however $f(x)$ might not be defined

@rafilou2003 yes but if I take only the points where this f is well defined ? the problem is this (it has to be defined everywhere)?

"if I take only the points where f is well defined?" Is this measurable then? We're in a circular argument

@ahh ok now I see really thanks... if f is measurable this method is also correct right?

"If $f$ is measurable" makes no sense. Which $f$? "let's call $f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$" You mean $f(x)$. But (again) this is not defined for every $x$.

See this answer, found using the search engine of MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=set+where+the+limit+exists+is+measurable

u can fix your approach by using cauchy criterion

@AnneBauval can you please tell me now if it is ok?

@Andrew can you please tell me now if it is ok?

@rafilou2003 can you please tell me now if it is ok?

No, because you appended a "moral" but didn't fix the main part of your post. So, now, the post is getting even more confused: we don't know what you are asking.

@AnneBauval I have said I am aware of the solution you proposed with your links, but I have  asked why I can't approach the problem  using my previous method ,and through your answer   I have said that the moral of the story was this. I didn't want to give a solution of the full problem I just wanted to know where was my mistake and stop . So it is ok my moral ?

No, because (again) you seem (in your update) to have understood why your method doesn't work, so there is no question left. Whence my "we don't know what you are asking".
